# Print a list of disk blocks used by file(s) - Linux

Tags: c, file-system, linux

This code takes a list of filenames as arguments or from stdin (or from a provided file) and dumps a list of disk blocks used by those files.

An attempt is made to use the linux `ioctl` function `fiemap` and if that fails (ex. on FAT filesystems) falls back to using the `fibmap` function.

This code compiles with VS Community 2017 on a Ubuntu Bionic system.

(Any suggestions as to better argument switches [such as using `-o` for `output file` and something else for `offset` will also be appreciated)

```
    /*
*
* This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
* modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
* as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2
* of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
*
* This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
* but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
* MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
* GNU General Public License for more details.
*
* You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
* along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
* Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301, USA.
*
*/

/*
*  Copyright (C) 2018 
*  Author afuna
*  parts Copyright (C) 2010 Canonical: Colin Ian King,  colin.king@canonical.com
*/



#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/fiemap.h>

void syntax(char **argv)
{
    printf("lsblocks - Dumps a list of blocks occupied by a file using FIEMAP or FIBMAP.\n");
    printf("\nUsage: %s [file1 file2...]\n", argv[0]);
    printf("\nYou can provide a list of newline delimited filenames from stdin.\n");
    printf("\nOptions:\n");
    printf(
        "  -h           show this help screen.\n"
        "  -v           print file information to stderr before dumping block numbers.\n"
        "               use -vv to print to the output file\n"
        "  -i <path>    read filenames from <path>\n"
        "  -s <path>    save output to <path>\n"
        "  -o <count>   offset values by <count>.\n"
        "  -d <dir>     change working directory to <dir>.\n"
        "  -f <format>  format block values using the given string;\n"
        "               you must provide the terminator (\\n or ' ' etc.)\n"
    );
}

static unsigned long long offset = 0;
static int verbosity = 0;
static char* format = NULL;
static char* infile = NULL;
static char* outfile = NULL;

static FILE* fd_in = NULL;
static FILE* fd_out = NULL;
static FILE* fd_info = NULL;

struct fiemap *read_fiemap(int fd)
{
    struct fiemap *fiemap;
    int extents_size;

    if ((fiemap = (struct fiemap*)malloc(sizeof(struct fiemap))) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory allocating fiemap\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    memset(fiemap, 0, sizeof(struct fiemap));

    fiemap->fm_start = 0;
    fiemap->fm_length = ~0;     /* Lazy */
    fiemap->fm_flags = 0;
    fiemap->fm_extent_count = 0;
    fiemap->fm_mapped_extents = 0;

    /* Find out how many extents there are */
    if (ioctl(fd, FS_IOC_FIEMAP, fiemap) < 0) {
        perror("fiemap ioctl() failed: ");
        //fprintf(stderr, "fiemap ioctl() failed\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    /* Read in the extents */
    extents_size = sizeof(struct fiemap_extent) *
        (fiemap->fm_mapped_extents);

    /* Resize fiemap to allow us to read in the extents */
    if ((fiemap = (struct fiemap*)realloc(fiemap, sizeof(struct fiemap) +
        extents_size)) == NULL) {
        perror("Out of memory allocating fiemap: ");
        return NULL;
    }

    memset(fiemap->fm_extents, 0, extents_size);
    fiemap->fm_extent_count = fiemap->fm_mapped_extents;
    fiemap->fm_mapped_extents = 0;

    if (ioctl(fd, FS_IOC_FIEMAP, fiemap) < 0) {
        perror("fiemap ioctl() failed: ");
        return NULL;
    }

    return fiemap;
}

void dump_fiemap(struct fiemap *fiemap, char *filename) {
    if (verbosity > 0)
        fprintf(fd_info, "blocksize %d\n", 512);

    for (int i = 0; i < fiemap->fm_mapped_extents; i++) {
        unsigned long long base = offset + (fiemap->fm_extents[i].fe_physical / 512);
        unsigned long long count = fiemap->fm_extents[i].fe_length / 512;
        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
            fprintf(fd_out, format, base++);
        }
    }
}

void dump_fibmap(int fd) {
    int block, blocksize, blkcnt;
    struct stat st;

    if (ioctl(fd, FIGETBSZ, &blocksize)) {
        perror("FIBMAP ioctl failed: ");
        return;
    }

    if (fstat(fd, &st)) {
        perror("fstat error");
        return;
    }

    blkcnt = (st.st_size + blocksize - 1) / blocksize;

    if (verbosity > 0)
        fprintf(fd_info, "size %d blocks %d blocksize %d\n", (int)st.st_size, blkcnt, blocksize);

    for (int i = 0; i < blkcnt; i++) {
        block = i;
        if (ioctl(fd, FIBMAP, &block)) {
            perror("FIBMAP ioctl failed: ");
        }
        else {
            int result;
            result = fprintf(fd_out, format, offset + block);
            if (result < 0) {
                perror("failed write: ");
            }
        }
    }
}

void dump(char* path)
{
    int fd;

    if ((fd = open(path, O_RDONLY)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open file %s\n", path);
        perror(NULL);
    }
    else {
        fprintf(fd_info, "Dumping file %s ", path);

        struct fiemap *fiemap;

        fiemap = read_fiemap(fd);
        fiemap != NULL ? dump_fiemap(fiemap, path) : dump_fibmap(fd);
        close(fd);
    }
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char* path = NULL;

    opterr = 0;

    int opt = 0;
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "o:f:d:i:s:vh")) != -1)
        switch (opt)
        {
        case 'o':
            offset = strtoull(optarg, NULL, 10);
            break;
        case 'f':
            format = optarg;
            break;
        case 'd':
            if (chdir(optarg) != 0) {
                perror("Failed to change working directory: ");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
            break;
        case 'i':
            infile = optarg;
            break;
        case 's':
            outfile = optarg;
        case 'v':
            verbosity++;
            break;
        case 'h':
            syntax(argv);
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        case '?':
            if (optopt == 'c')
                fprintf(stderr, "Option -%c requires an argument.\n", optopt);
            else if (isprint(optopt))
                fprintf(stderr, "Unknown option '-%c'.\n", optopt);
            else
                fprintf(stderr, "Unknown option character '\\x%x'.\n", optopt);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        default:
            abort();
        }

    if (format == NULL)
        format = "%llu\n";

    if (infile == NULL)
        fd_in = stdin;
    else if ((fd_in = fopen(infile, "rb")) == NULL) {
        perror("Cannot open input file: ");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (outfile == NULL)
        fd_out = stdout;
    else if ((fd_out = fopen(outfile, "w")) == NULL) {
        perror("Cannot open output file: ");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fd_info = verbosity <= 1 ? stderr : fd_out;

    if (optind == argc | infile != NULL) { // read stdin or infile
        char *buffer;
        size_t bufsize = 2048;
        size_t characters;

        buffer = (char *)malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char));
        if (buffer == NULL)
        {
            perror("Unable to allocate buffer");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        int size = 0;
        while ((size = getline(&buffer, &bufsize, fd_in)) > 0)
        {
            buffer[size - 1] = '\0';
            dump(buffer);
        }
    }
    else {
        for (int idx = optind; idx < argc; idx++)
            dump(argv[idx]);
    }

    if (fd_in != stdin && !fclose(fd_in)) {
        perror("Failed to close input file: ");
    }

    fflush(fd_out);
    if (fd_out != stdout && fclose(fd_out)) {
        perror("Failed to close output file: ");
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Command options

The `-i` option isn't needed - any competent user can simply use `xargs` to achieve the same effect with more flexibility (e.g. using NUL-delimited stream, to correctly handle names with embedded newline characters).

Similarly, the `-s` option is pointless, as shell redirection is simpler for the user (more consistent than finding a program-specific option).

The `-d` option doesn't have value either, as that's something that all shells provide.

The `-f` option is **dangerous**, as there's no validation that the string contains a single `%llu` conversion, with no other conversion specifiers (e.g. `%n`, which can cause modification of the process memory).

> ```
>         else if (isprint(optopt))
>             fprintf(stderr, "Unknown option '-%c'.\n", optopt);
>         else
>             fprintf(stderr, "Unknown option character '\\x%x'.\n", optopt);
> ```

These error messages should tell the user to use the `-h` option for the full help.

> ```
>     case 's':
>         outfile = optarg;
>     case 'v':
>         verbosity++;
>         break;
> ```

I don't think that `-s` should also increase verbosity, so I recommend adding `break;` before `case 'v'`.

## Memory allocation

Consider

> ```
> if ((fiemap = (struct fiemap*)malloc(sizeof(struct fiemap))) == NULL) {
>     fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory allocating fiemap\n");
>     return NULL;
> }
> ```

In C, `malloc()` returns a `void*`, which is assignable to any other pointer type, so the cast is just visual clutter.  Common practice is to use the size of the pointer target, so we don't have to find the definition of `fiemap` to see whether it matches:

```
fiemap = malloc(sizeof *fiemap)
```

All the error returns fail to free `fiemap`, meaning that memory is leaked in these cases.

We also have a leak here (a common antipattern in C):

```
fiemap = realloc(fiemap, sizeof *fiemap + extents_size)
```

When `realloc()` fails, we overwrite the pointer variable with a null pointer, meaning that we are unable to free the memory.  Always assign to a temporary pointer, and only overwrite the original if the `realloc()` was successful.

In `main()` there's a pointless multiplication by `sizeof (char)` (which is always 1, since `sizeof` measures in units of `char`).

## Improve function safety

> ```
> void dump_fiemap(struct fiemap *fiemap, char *filename)
> ```

There's no reason to be modifying either of these values, so make the function safer with `const`:

```
void dump_fiemap(const struct fiemap *fiemap, const char *filename)
```

The `filename` argument doesn't even seem to be used - just remove it.

Similarly, `dump()` should accept a `const char*`, and `format` should be a `const char*` (since we assign it from a string literal).

## Careful with integer conversions

> ```
> fiemap->fm_length = ~0;
> ```

Can you be sure that promotion of the `int` value (-1) to `__u64` works as you expect?  I'd be kinder to the reader and write `~(__u64)0`, or perhaps just use the provided `FIEMAP_MAX_OFFSET`.

`extents_size` ought to be a `size_t`, not `int`.  And the loop indices in `dump_fiemap()` should be unsigned, not signed.

These simple inconsistencies suggest the code has been compiled with insufficient warnings enabled.  I recommend `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-parentheses -Wpedantic -Warray-bounds -Wstrict-prototypes -Wconversion`, which will highlight these problems, and more.